# Angular Routerlink : Concatenate Parent Route String with Variable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

How do I add string interpolation/concatenation

to router link below which goes to parent route, and then variable link?

```
 <a routerLink="../account-information/" + "item.productId">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String Interpolation

```
routerLink="../account-information/{{item.productId}}"
```

Attribute Binding Syntax:

```
[routerLink]="'../account-information/' +item.productId"
```

or

```
[routerLink]="['../account-information/', item.productId]"
```